# Multi-threaded cURL with SSL

Tags: php, curl

I found this code: http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/

```
<?php

function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}
```

It seems to work fine, except when I pass it URLs with `https`. I'm guessing that I should either pass it $options to handle SSL or modify the code and add a `curl_setopt`. The problem is that I do not know which option to add to make this work with SSL. Suggestions?

Comment: What specific SSL [settings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) did you anticipate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty(trust everyone!)

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Properly, more work because you have to save the certificate of the website to disc so curl can use it to verify the website

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/CAcerts/BuiltinObjectToken-EquifaxSecureCA.crt");
```

For more info the source I used(1st result on google "curl ssl")

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: is there a way to use
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
in multi curl?

Comment: You should ask a new question. @asdru